# Recount each user's total post and update in database in SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So I have this script that needs to Update total uploads per user and store into the users table.

I have a function that can count the number of uploads made by each user but not stored into database, my site is already live and a busy site that I can't update this manually since the posts are non-stop.

Below is my function to count the uploads...

```
function get_row_count($table, $suffix = "") {
   $res = SQL_Query_exec("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $table $suffix");
   $row = mysql_fetch_row($res);
  return $row[0];
```

}

The users table looks like this

```
[users table]
 id             username        numuploads      numcomments
```

the uploads table looks like this

```
[uploads table]
  fileid      userid          added             enabled
```

So how can I run an SQL query to count the number of uploads per user from the uploads table and update it into each user's numuploads at once without doing it manually.

Thanks..

**EDIT**

```
UPDATE users SET numuploads = (SELECT COUNT(id) as numuploads FROM uploads WHERE owner = users.id)
```

**Problem is solved now**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of selecting the the count as a separate query, then adding `1` and updating some DB column, You could do directly the update only:

```sql
UPDATE table SET number = number + 1 WHERE id = <ID>
```

This query should be run each time when a new comment/upload is done by that user and requires the *number* column to be of numeric type with default value set to 0 (zero). The above query is just an example that You should change to meet Your DB scheme.